# sql server agent cmdexe: access denied

Tags: sql-server-2008, cmd, remote-access, sql-agent-job

I want to run an exe on a remote computer. I have set up as follows:

1. Step Type is: operating System (cmdExec)
2. Command: "\xxxxxx\c$\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx.exe"
   Proxy user - my login

Troubleshooting:

1. I log in as me on both boxes (sql and exe boxes) - no issues
2. I access the remote box containing exe via run - no issues
3. I run the exe manually - no issues
4. All other steps which run either SSIS or local exes run with proxy account - no issues
5. I changed th esql serve agent service to use localhost or my creds - still see issue

Anybody have any idea why i can run everything manually but when i setr up a sql server agent job to simply run a exe on a remote comp it wont work??

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. When you authenticate remote under an impersonated context the Kerberos Constrained Delegation rules kick in (aka. 'double hop'). When you connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication you are running an impersonated context. When you connect using SQL authentication remote access uses the configured proxy login for that SQL login.

All your 'success'  cases all fall either on the side where there is no double-hop or there is a proxy user that can be used. All your failed cases are 'double-hop' with a Windows authentication login (hence using impersonation, not a proxy user).

The problem, as described, is really trivial to fix: copy the "\host\c$\path\program.exe" locally to your SQL instance host  and run it locally ("c:\path\program.exe"). There are more reasons for this, aside from avoiding the double-hop. But is very likely that the program itself will require remote access and that *will* trigger constrained delegation.

So the proper fix is to [set up constrained delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc995228.aspx) *for the specific service you want to access*. Which is a real pain, but it the only way forward. Talk to your network and domain admins how to do it, they must be involved (it requires certain privileges only they have) and they know how to do it. In Windows 2012 is much easier to set up, see [How Windows Server 2012 Eases the Pain of Kerberos Constrained Delegation, Part 1](http://windowsitpro.com/security/how-windows-server-2012-eases-pain-kerberos-constrained-delegation-part-1).

Comment: 'copy the "\host\c$\path\program.exe" locally to your SQL instance host and run it locally ("c:\path\program.exe"). ' this isn't an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a satisfactory hack which isn't so offensive as to be invalid...
I created a bat to be triggered by the SQL agent. the Bat file fires the desired exe.

why this doesn't see the same access issues I don't know but I'm glad it doesn't :)

bat file contents

```
start \\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxx.exe
```